# Generate consecutive table rows using jquery?

Tags: jquery

**Question 01:**

I am trying to generate consecutive table rows after the following row using jquery..

here's my default row html code:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Slot 01</b></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="delvDate1" name="delvDate[]" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvQnty1" name="delvQnty[]" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvBalance1" name="delvBalance[]" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvRemarks1" name="delvRemarks[]" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
```

here's my jquery code:

```
var MaxInputs = 7; //maximum input fields allowed
var InputsWrapper = $("#deliveryStatusTable tr").first().next().prev(); //Input fields wrapper ID
var AddButton = $("#addAnotherDeliveryStatus"); //Add button ID
var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text fields count
var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text fields added
$(AddButton).click(function(e)  //on add input button click
{
    if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount = FieldCount + 1; //text box added increment
//add input box
        $(InputsWrapper).after(
                '<tr id="idleRow' + FieldCount + '"><td><b>Slot 0' + FieldCount + '</b></td><td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="delvDate' + FieldCount + '" name="delvDate[]" value="delvDate' + FieldCount + '" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvQnty' + FieldCount + '" name="delvQnty[]" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvBalance' + FieldCount + '" name="delvBalance[]" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvRemarks' + FieldCount + '" name="delvRemarks[]" required="required" /></td></tr>'
                );
        x++; //text box increment
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here's what I'm getting in outputs:
[image]

I need slot01, slot02, slot03....and so on

not slot08, slot07, slot06...

**Question 02:**

In this same table in the delivery date field a bootstrap calendar is displaying like below pic:

[image]

but in other fields the calendar UI isn't showing. I have already wrote code for those fields..like below:

```
$('#delvDate1').datetimepicker({
  pickTime: false
});

$('#delvDate2').datetimepicker({
  pickTime: false
});

$('#delvDate3').datetimepicker({
  pickTime: false
});
```

Here I've checked that the id value is alright. Then why only the first one working, but the others are not???

please help me out here...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)what happens if you change to last here?

```
var InputsWrapper   = $("#deliveryStatusTable tr").last().prev();
```

It should append it at the end this way.

2)change this part of code to initialize the new datepickers:

```
if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount = FieldCount + 1; //text box added increment
        lasttr= $("#deliveryStatusTable tr").last().prev();
        $(lasttr).after(
                '<tr id="idleRow' + FieldCount + '"><td><b>Slot 0' + FieldCount + '</b></td><td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="delvDate' + FieldCount + '" name="delvDate[]" value="delvDate' + FieldCount + '" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvQnty' + FieldCount + '" name="delvQnty[]" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvBalance' + FieldCount + '" name="delvBalance[]" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvRemarks' + FieldCount + '" name="delvRemarks[]" required="required" /></td></tr>'
                );
        $('#delvDate' + FieldCount).datepicker();
        x++; //text box increment
    }
```

I fixed the part 1)

EDIT: i refixed your code. There were some mistakes:

```
var MaxInputs = 7; //maximum input fields allowed
var InputsWrapper = $("#deliveryStatusTable tr").last().prev(); //Input fields wrapper ID
var AddButton = $("#addAnotherDeliveryStatus"); //Add button ID
var x = 1;
var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text fields added
$(AddButton).click(function(e)  //on add input button click
{
    if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount = FieldCount + 1; //text box added increment
//add input box
      lasttr=$("#deliveryStatusTable tr").last().prev();
        $(lasttr).after(
                '<tr id="idleRow' + FieldCount + '"><td><b>Slot 0' + FieldCount + '</b></td><td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="delvDate' + FieldCount + '" name="delvDate[]" value="delvDate' + FieldCount + '" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvQnty' + FieldCount + '" name="delvQnty[]" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvBalance' + FieldCount + '" name="delvBalance[]" required="required" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="delvRemarks' + FieldCount + '" name="delvRemarks[]" required="required" /></td></tr>'
                );
        x++; //text box increment
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry i just corrected the id name on the line i added.

Comment: 1) unfortunately the new row added after the buttons row...

2) datetime is totally working now..:)..thanks

Comment: i re-fixed it. With prev() it should go back to the previous tr (the one before the buttons.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the last row contains the two buttons...that's why I need to add rows one step up from the last row..

Comment: doesn't work with .prev() after the code i gave you? where does the new line go in this case?

Comment: same thing as I mentioned in first comment...I wish I could upload the screenshot in comment..

Comment: you can see that the button is still at the end and the second line is in  between

Comment: if it still doesn't work can you show me exactly the html structure of the table? maybe you can past it in jsbin

Comment: oh there was another problem i think. You should move the definition of inputswrapper inside the loop. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry to keep u waiting so long....I have pasted my HTML code in jsbin...
Here's the link: "http://jsbin.com/fejukobo/2/"

Comment: after putting the inputswrapper inside the loop...the sequence is working but still those rows are being added after the button row..

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Q1. Try replacing this line:

```
$(InputsWrapper).after(
```

with:

```
$("#deliveryStatusTable").append(
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dB452/)

Comment: nah...not working either..but thanks for patiently reading all these codes...:)